# iOS Document/File type associations - SVG

Tags: ios, svg, uti

I am working on an SVG editor of sorts for iOS. Working with files via (iTunes) File Sharing works nicely, but I also want to make the app handle SVGs system wide - mail attachments, airdrops, SVGs on webpages etc.

For UTI known to iOS (like PDF) this is easy. For a custom UTI it's a little more work - defining exported UTI etc - but works nicely.

Now, SVG is a different story. There is an official UTI public.svg-image, but it is not known to iOS. I have tried many combinations of Document Type and Imported / Exported UTI, but nothing seems to convince iOS that my app can deal with SVG files. LSHandlerRank make no difference, and iOS does not care about CFBundleTypeRole.

Is it simply not possible to register as an editor of the SVG file format on iOS?

Below is a minimal setup that *should* work according to docs.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
    <string>SVG File</string>
    <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <array>
      <string>public.svg-image</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>

<key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
    <array>
      <string>public.image</string>
    </array>
    <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
    <string>Scalable Vector Graphics</string>
    <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
    <string>public.svg-image</string>
    <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
    <dict>
      <key>public.filename-extension</key>
      <array>
        <string>svg</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Ever found a solution for this?

Comment: I am also looking at this exact problem. Has anyone every figured this out for SVGs?